# Why do I get errors and slow connections times in my multi threaded client app?

Tags: python, multithreading, dns, python-requests

I'm trying to get json data from an api. I need to do a lot of requests to the server and I'm doing it in a multi threaded fashion. I have a large list of ids and I do one get requests per id. I then save each individual json response to a list.

```
import requests
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

def doWork():
    while True:
        item_id = q.get()
        item = get_json(item_id)
        items.append(item)
        q.task_done()

def get_json(item_id):
    link = 'https://my-api.com/item/{}.json'.format(item_id)
    json_response = requests.get(link).json()
    return json_response

concurrent = 64
items = []

q = Queue(concurrent)
for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=doWork)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for item_id in range(500):
    q.put(item_id)
q.join()
```

If I set this loose on a large number of ids (more than a few thounsand) I always end up getting 'Temporary failure in name resolution' connections errors. If I pace myself and only run it on something like 500 ids it works but if I run it too frequently I still get errors.

I tried running it in a loop for blocks of 500 ids and sleeping between requests, and between blocks but I still end up with a bunch of errors and the connection speed slows down.

How can I tell what's causing my problems?

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: which operating system are you on? any exceptions you could catch that provide further information?

Comment: I've added the OS. It's Ubuntu 15.04. The only exception I get is ConnectionError: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: It looks like you're making all those requests to the same host. That means you could (should) be using [`requests` sessions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) in order to take advantage of connection pooling. This will give you [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), which means you can avoid doing a three-way TCP handshake for every single request to establish a connection, and avoid repeated DNS lookups, which both should improve your performance considerably.

Comment: Also see: [Requests Toolbelt: Using requests with Threading](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/threading.html)

Comment: Yes, I switched to sessions and everything ran smoothly. Thank you!